# JPA/Hibernate @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY) не работает

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

Здравствуйте. Пишу дипломный проект, после проверки получил замечание что в моём случае lazy не будет работать. Вопрос что не так?

```
@Entity
@javax.persistence.Table(name = "Tables")
public class Table implements Serializable {
    ...

    @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "order_id", unique = true)
    private Order order;

    ...
}

@Entity
@javax.persistence.Table(name = "orders")
public class Order implements Serializable {
    ...

    @OneToOne(mappedBy = "order", fetch = FetchType.LAZY, optional = false)
    private Table table;

    ...
}
```

Подскажите в чём соль.

Comment: Отложенная загрузка предполагает, что отношение будет загружено в момент обращения к соответствующему полю экземпляра сущности. Так покажите код, в котором это обращение происходит. Может у вас к этому моменту сессия уже закрыта.

Comment: Да и смысла здесь в отложенной загрузке нет, это только увеличит нагрузку на базу.

Comment: Да не в том дело. Тут дело в том что без обращения к полю обьект выгружает.

Comment: Вы проверяли? А то я только что, для уверенности, накидал две сущности с точно таким же отношением и проверил. Если не обращаться к полю order сущности `Table`, то запроса к таблице `Order` не происходит. Если обращаться, то происходит, притом отдельно для каждого экземпляра `Table`. По всем признакам lazy load работает.

Comment: Да вот в том и соль, что вроде всё нормально, а замечание в работе стоит. Думал может какойто подвог здесь есть.

Comment: Тут какая то специфическая проблемма, вот здесь обсуждение http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1444227/making-a-onetoone-relation-lazy

Comment: У автора вопроса по приведённой вами ссылке вылетает исключение при доступе к ленивым отношениям. Не ваш случай. А в принятом ответе ему объяснили, что на nullabel one-to-one не навешивается прокси. Опять не ваш случай.

Answer (score 1):

У вас двунаправленная связь. В то время как однонаправленная @OneToOne ассоциация может быть извлечена лениво, родительская сторона двунаправленной @OneToOne ассоциации - нет. Даже когда указывается, что ассоциация не существует, (optional=false) и у нас есть FetchType.LAZY, родительская ассоциация будет вести себя как FetchType.EAGER. 
Прочтите вот это:

[Лучший способ отобразить отношения @OneToOne с JPA и Hibernate](https://vladmihalcea.com/the-best-way-to-map-a-onetoone-relationship-with-jpa-and-hibernate)